# NPOI is generating a 0 bytes stream

Tags: c#, npoi

I am using a C# code that works perfectly in other projects.... but in this one, it is returning a 0 bytes length stream.

This is how I am saving the stream:

```
        using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            return exportData.ToArray();
        }
```

workbook is correctly formed, and in fact, as I have told you, this code works in other projects.

In this case, I am using NPOI 2.4.0 and SharpZipLib 0.86.0. I have found similar issues telling that the problem is SharpZipkib version, but this is not my case.

What else can this be causing the problem? It is a shame that NPOI does not  even send any exception.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the SharpZipLib version definition in web.config.

The solution was explained in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509952/found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-icsharpcode-sharpziplib-that-cou) which I posted an answer myself.