# Found conflicts between different versions of "ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" that could not be resolved

Tags: c#, nuget-package, sharpziplib

I am using NPOI in my MVC 5 project. When I installed it via Nuget, I have installed SharpLib 0.86 because it is a dependency.

After doing this, NPOI generates a 0 bytes file. When I build the solution, this error appears in error list:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

I am sure NPOI does not work properly cause of this.

What's the matter? Why such a conflict exists since this is the only installation of SharpZipLib?

I set the build log as detailed, but it is not taken into account.

EDIT:

This is the web.config file where dependencies are defined:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.1" newVersion="4.0.3.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.999" newVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.999" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Try to use a redirection in the web.config file. Otherwise, try to install `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib` directly as a NuGet package so that it's not an implicit reference

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have found in Web.config this line, under SharpZipLib dependentAssembly: <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.999" newVersion="1.0.0.999" />. I changed in both places the version by 0.86.0.518 and the error is gone now, and miraculously NPOI worked too!! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. You can post that as an answer and I'll vote for that, but make sure to edit your question to include the relevant web.config file so that people know what to look for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that this definition in web.config was the problem:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.999" newVersion="1.0.0.999" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I realized that version defined was 1.0.0.999, instead of 0.86.0.518, which is actually used. I don't know when that definition was added. Maybe it was due because SharpZipLib 1 was installed before and after downgrade, definition was not modified by NuGet package manager.

I manually changed it to:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.86.0.518" newVersion="0.86.0.518" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and error is gone.

Furthermore, my guess was correct: NPOI started working too.

Regards
Jaime